# How can I write this else if statement more efficiently?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a page with some css custom buttons and I want the selected button to stay highlighted when a user clicks elsewhere on the page. 
I can get what I want writing an if/else statement to assign a class when a button is selected and a different class if it's not selected but it's long winded, how can I write it to be more efficient?

```
<input class="btn" id="moveIt_overall2" type="button" value="Overall" onclick="changeImpactState('impact_overall');"/>
<input class="btn" id="moveIt_customer" type="button" value="Customer" onclick="changeImpactState('impact_customer');" />
<input class="btn" id="moveIt_staff" type="button" value="Staff" onclick="changeImpactState('impact_staff');" />
<input class="btn" id="moveIt_strategic" type="button" value="Strategic" onclick="changeImpactState('impact_strategic');" />
```

```
var moveItOverall = document.getElementById('moveIt_overall2');
var moveItCustomer = document.getElementById('moveIt_customer');
var moveItStaff = document.getElementById('moveIt_staff');
var moveItStrategic = document.getElementById('moveIt_strategic');

if(currentImpactState == 'impact_overall'){
    moveItOverall.className = 'btn-on';
    moveItCustomer.className = 'btn';
    moveItStaff.className = 'btn';
    moveItStrategic.className = 'btn';
}else if(currentImpactState == 'impact_customer'){
    moveItOverall.className = 'btn';
    moveItCustomer.className = 'btn-on';
    moveItStaff.className = 'btn';
    moveItStrategic.className = 'btn';
}else if(currentImpactState == 'impact_staff'){
    moveItOverall.className = 'btn';
    moveItCustomer.className = 'btn';
    moveItStaff.className = 'btn-on';
    moveItStrategic.className = 'btn';
}else if(currentImpactState == 'impact_strategic'){
    moveItOverall.className = 'btn';
    moveItCustomer.className = 'btn';
    moveItStaff.className = 'btn';
    moveItStrategic.className = 'btn-on';
}
```

Comment: Use `Switch` statements rather than long tails of if else. Switch provides more readability and better performance

Comment: You can set them all initially, then specifically set the one you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple improvement example.

```
moveItOverall.className = 'btn';
moveItCustomer.className = 'btn';
moveItStaff.className = 'btn';
moveItStrategic.className = 'btn';

if(currentImpactState == 'impact_overall'){
    moveItOverall.className = 'btn-on';
}else if(currentImpactState == 'impact_customer'){
    moveItCustomer.className = 'btn-on';
}else if(currentImpactState == 'impact_staff'){
    moveItStaff.className = 'btn-on';
}else if(currentImpactState == 'impact_strategic'){
    moveItStrategic.className = 'btn-on';
}
```

**Update**

Because `forEach` is not supported in earlier version browser, change Mark Meyer's answer to simple JavaScript as below:

```
const buttons = {
    impact_overall: 'moveIt_overall2',
    impact_customer: 'moveIt_customer',
    impact_staff: 'moveIt_staff',
    impact_strategic: 'moveIt_strategic'
}

for(var key in buttons)
{
    // if key equals currentImpactState
    // then set className as btn-on
    // else set to 'btn'
    document.getElementById(buttons[key]).className = (currentImpactState == key)? 'btn-on' : 'btn';
}
```

Comment: This answer is much easier for me to understand but @Mark-Meyer's answer works and looks super efficient.

Comment: Changing my answer to this one as it works in IE, Chrome and Edge. Mark Meyer's answer doesn't work in IE.

Comment: I guess that because your IE version (maybe under 9) doesn't support that JavaScript version (forEach in ES5).

Comment: thanks for the tip re ES5. I'm using IE11 and your answer works perfect IE, Edge and Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

You are essentially mapping your `currentImpactState` to an ID in your DOM. You can explicitly make this map and then use it to find the object you want to change.

```
const buttons = {
    impact_overall: 'moveIt_overall2',
    impact_customer: 'moveIt_customer',
    impact_staff: 'moveIt_staff',
    impact_strategic: 'moveIt_strategic'
}

// change everything
Object.values(buttons).forEach(id => document.getElementById(id).className = 'btn' )
// change the item currentImpactState indicates
document.getElementById(buttons[currentImpactState]).className = 'btn-on'
```

Comment: You beat me to it again @mark-meyer! Working fiddle here :) https://jsfiddle.net/stwilz/c7e9ra84/20/

Comment: Be careful. It will throw an error when the `currentImpactState` value is unknown.

Comment: Yes @Finesse, that's a good point. I'm assuming here that `currentImpactState` is a known enumeration of values, but if it wasn't you'd certainly want to check that it's a valid property of `buttons`.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the second part of the `currentImpactState` string, and then iterate over an array of the IDs, checking whether the ID includes the substring or not. If it does, set to `btn-on`, else set to `btn`:

```
const substr = currentImpactState.slice(7);
['moveIt_overall2', 'moveIt_customer', 'moveIt_staff', 'moveIt_strategic'].forEach(id => {
  const element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.className = id.includes(substr)
    ? 'btn-on'
    : 'btn';
});
```